# Upgrading from Qgis 2.4 to 2.12 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

This should be a simple question. On Ubuntu 15.04 how can I get Qgis upgraded from 2.4 to 2.12?

Comment: What version do you have in your repository? I do a 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade' and I get the newest version from the QGIS repository (vs. the UBUNTUGIS repo...)

Answer (score 7):

The Ubuntugis unstable ppa does not offer new versions of QGIS anymore.

So you have to add qgis.org to your repositories to get the newest versions.

See https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu for instructions.

Apart from editing the sources.list, you can use the Ubuntu Software Center to add the additional repositories as well.

---

I am using Linux Mint 17.3, and I added the ubuntugis ppa with

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu trusty main
```

and qgis.org as additional repository:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
```

You would have to switch from trusty to vivid. Both need a key, in my case 314DF160 and D71472C4.

After that, run in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache policy qgis
```

and you should see what is installed and what you can upgrade to.

Comment: OK I have tried but adding 'deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/ vivid main' or 'deb http://qgis.org/debian/ vivid main' to my sources.list will still not pull down Qgis 2.12.

Comment: Did you miss the `http://`, the qgis keyring and maybe a restart?

Comment: The 'comment' editor hides the http:// but yes it was there. I tried the Lubuntu Software Center also. What **exactly** should I be entering as the full string? 'ppa'? 'deb'? 'ubuntu vivid'?

Comment: See my extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. I found a page with a good link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/645343/how-do-i-install-qgis-2-8-on-ubuntu-15-04

[EDITED SLIGHTLY]
To install the newest version of QGIS I added the QGIS repositories to my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

sudo leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list

and inserted these lines:

deb http://qgis.org/debian vivid main

deb-src http://qgis.org/debian vivid main

Remember to add the GPG keys as follows:

gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3FF5FFCAD71472C4

gpg --export --armor 3FF5FFCAD71472C4 | sudo apt-key add -

Then run:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass

This installed qgis 2.12.3-Lyon