# Grid Error – Natural neighbour

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-processing, saga

I am getting the following Error on using `Natural neighbour`. There were solutions suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/failed-dem-via-natural-neighbor-in-qgis-2-14-2-essen) & [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221924/the-following-layers-were-not-correctly-generated-grid/230790#230790). But these works fine on Windows but not on Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, QGIS 2.18.4 & SAGA 2.2.7.
What could be the solution for ubuntu ?

[image]

Comment: Try to upgrade QGIS to the latest LTR version 2.14.12. It may solve the proplem.

Comment: @ahmadhanb .... Thanks for responding. I managed to come back from  Qgis 2.18 to Qgis 2.14.3. Then, tried to upgrade to 2.14.12  but failed. Any help to upgrade. Thanks

Comment: What is the latest QGIS LTR for ubuntu is available? In windows the latest is 2.14.12, but maybe in ubuntu not yet, so please check the latest version and upgrade.

Comment: There seems 2.14.12 ltr for ubuntu too. Tried a lot to upgrade, but failed. Looks, this is beyond my skills and capacity.

Comment: I am not familiar with ubuntu but try to follow the instructions in this thread http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178017/upgrading-from-qgis-2-4-to-2-12-on-ubuntu-15-04